# MinGW standard library static linking

Tags: mingw, static-linking

I have a simple program which uses standard library functions like malloc(), free() and I want to link them statically. I tried options: -static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc but nothing is working.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the evidence that it doesn't seem to be linked as you expect, so that others can try to reproduce your problem

Comment: Also specify exactly which compiler build you are using  . (If using pre-built binaries, say where you got them)